# How can I move a box inserted in a line to the left edge of the page?

Tags: beamer, margins, alignment

I am trying to use a notification for an upcoming note page. The notification is a small box shown simultaneously with the note that precedes the note page. I would like the box to go to the very right of the page with absolutely 0mm margin with respect to its edge.

This is what I get

[image]

This is what I want

[image]

It would also be great if the box is inserted automatically and simultaneously with every instant of `\note<+>`, but it should still be aligned with the item that precedes the note

Another issue is that the box is not aligned with the middle of the text words. Is there a way to align both centers together?

[image]

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}

    \setbeameroption{show notes}
    \newcommand{\itemUncoverMoreContents}{\item<+->}
    \newcommand{\presentUncoverMoreContents}{\uncover<+->}

    \usecolortheme{wolverine}
    \useoutertheme[]{split}
    \useinnertheme{inmargin}

            \newlength{\widthTextMarginLeft}
            \setlength{\widthTextMarginLeft}{1.5mm}
            \newlength{\widthTextMarginRight}
            \setlength{\widthTextMarginRight}{2mm}

            \setbeamersize{text margin left=\widthTextMarginLeft, text margin right=\widthTextMarginRight}

        \newlength{\sidebarWidth}
        \setlength{\sidebarWidth}{0.3\paperwidth}

        \setbeamersize{sidebar width left=\sidebarWidth, sidebar width right=0cm}




    % ===== Customize the note page =====
    % ===================================

% BEGIN_FOLD

        % Determine note page geometry
        \makeatletter
        \ifbeamer@notesnormals%
        \beamer@paperwidth 16.00cm%
        \beamer@paperheight 9.00cm%
        %           \beamer@leftmargin 10mm%
        %           \beamer@rightmargin 12mm%
        \geometry{papersize={\beamer@paperwidth,\beamer@paperheight}}
        \fi%
        \makeatother

        % Note page layout 2
        \usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
        \usetikzlibrary{calc}
        \newlength{\widthNotePageSlideContentClearance}
        \setlength{\widthNotePageSlideContentClearance}{5mm}
        \newlength{\notepageLeftMargin}
        \setlength{\notepageLeftMargin}{5mm}
        \newcommand{\insertNotePagePreview}{
            \adjustbox{rotate=90, max height=0.997\paperheight,  frame,valign=t}{\insertslideintonotes{1}}
                                        }
        \newcommand{\measureremainder}[1]{%
            \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]%
                % Measure distance to right text border
                \path let \p0 = (0,0), \p1 = (current page.east) in
                [/utils/exec={\pgfmathsetlength#1{\x1-\x0}\global#1=#1}];
            \end{tikzpicture}%
                                        }

        \newlength{\insertnoteWidth}

        \makeatletter
        \setbeamertemplate{note page}{

            % Slide preview

                \hskip-\Gm@lmargin%
                \insertNotePagePreview%
            %
            % The notes (the comments below must stay where they are)
            %
                \hspace{\widthNotePageSlideContentClearance}%
                \measureremainder{\insertnoteWidth}%
                \addtolength{\insertnoteWidth}{-\notepageLeftMargin}% this comment must stay 
                \begin{minipage}[t]{\insertnoteWidth}
                    \justifying
                    \insertnote
                \end{minipage}%
                                    }
        \makeatother

        \setbeamerfont{note page}{size=\normalsize}





% END_FOLD


\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setbeamersize{description width=0mm}


\usepackage{efbox}          

\newcommand{\notepageUpcoming}{\setbeamercolor{note page alert}{bg=DarkOrange2}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=3mm,wd=3mm]{note page alert}\end{beamercolorbox}}

\newcommand{\noteAlert}{%
    \hspace{\fill}\uncover<.>{\adjustbox{raise=0.03\baselineskip}{\notepageUpcoming}}
                            }



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Showing Contents Gradually without Alert}

    \begin{block}{Why is induction motor very common}
        %
        \presentUncoverMoreContents{Induction motors are very practical for the following reasons}

        \begin{description}
            \itemUncoverMoreContents[Rigid] Rigid
            \itemUncoverMoreContents[Cheap] Cheap
                \note<+>{\blindlistlist[1]{enumerate}}
                \noteAlert
            \itemUncoverMoreContents[Low Maintenance] Low Maintenance
            \itemUncoverMoreContents[Self-Starting] Self-starting
            \itemUncoverMoreContents[No Excitation Needed] No Excitation Needed
                \note<+>{\blindlistlist[1]{enumerate}}
                \noteAlert
            \itemUncoverMoreContents[Something goes here] Extra contents
        \end{description}

        \vspace{\fill}

        More content

    \end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little `tikz`-foo:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}

\setbeameroption{show notes}

\usecolortheme{rose}
\useinnertheme{inmargin}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=30}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Uncovering Contents with Alert}

\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item[Rigid] Rigid
    \item[Cheap] Cheap
    \item[Low Maintenance] Low Maintenance%    
    \note<3>{note text}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay ,remember picture]
        \node (foo) {};
        \fill<.>[orange] let \p1 = (foo),
                            \p2 = (current page.west)
        in (\x2,\y1) rectangle ++(0.2,0.2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \item[Self-Starting] Self-starting
    \item[No Excitation Needed] No Excitation Needed
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Simplified version, thanks a lot @PaulGaborit!

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}

\setbeameroption{show notes}

\usecolortheme{rose}
\useinnertheme{inmargin}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=30}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Uncovering Contents with Alert}

\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item[Rigid] Rigid
    \item[Cheap] Cheap
    \item[Low Maintenance] Low Maintenance%    
    \note<3>{note text}%
    \tikz[overlay ,remember picture]{\fill[orange] (0,0 -| current page.west) rectangle ++(0.2,0.2);}
    \item[Self-Starting] Self-starting
    \item[No Excitation Needed] No Excitation Needed
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I almost always customize the codes to In this code, what exactly do I need to modify to change the color of the notification box?

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh To modify the colour you can use `\fill<.>[orange]`

Comment: Good. One final thing, the original post shows that the alert box is transparent until it is uncovered but this one is entirely invisible up to the point of uncovered its adjacent item. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh `\fill[orange]`

Comment: Without the `foo` node nor the `let` operation, you can use `(0,0 -| current page.west)`...

Comment: @PaulGaborit Oh, that's indeed much simpler! Thanks a lot for your comment!