# Automatically stretch a figure to the largest possible height without crossing to the foot (beamer)

Tags: beamer, floats

I frequently need to get a figure to be as large as possible with some text being written next to it. However, I do this by trial and error but want more systematic way to do it.

Usually, what I want is something like this

[image]

As you can see, the figure has some comments next to it and it is manually tuned to stretch until it reaches the foot. When the text above the figure changes, the figure may either cross to the foot (where a part of it will not be visible) or go up (which means that an empty space will be left under it). Either case is not desirable. **In short, I want the figure height to be automatically adjusted depending on the contents around it.**

Here is a code that helps (obtained from [How can I move a box inserted in a line to the left edge of the page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480020/how-can-i-move-a-box-inserted-in-a-line-to-the-left-edge-of-the-page)
)

```
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
% Distance to the right margin
\newcommand{\measureRemainderToRightMargin}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
        % Measure distance to right text border
        \path let \p0 = (0,0), \p1 = (current page.east) in
        [/utils/exec={\pgfmathsetlength#1{\x1-\x0}\global#1=#1}];
    \end{tikzpicture}%
                                            }
```

The code above simply measures the distance to the right of the frame and stores it in its argument which is a length. **If the code is modified to measure the distance to the bottom and subtract the foot height from it, we would be able to determine the needed height.**

One more thing to note, which is even more complex to solve. If the contents to the left of the figure stretches over long width, the figure itself may exceed the right margin when stretches until the foot. Thus, the figure dimensions should be determined using the following (whichever results in smaller dimensions)

1. The height must not exceed the foot (rectangle 1)
2. The width must not exceed the right margin (rectangle 2)

Example code

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names},c]{beamer}

    \setbeamercovered{transparent=30}

    \usecolortheme{seahorse}
    \useoutertheme{miniframes}
    \useinnertheme{inmargin}

    \usepackage{adjustbox}

\newlength{\widthSideBar}
\setlength{\widthSideBar}{0.3\paperwidth}

\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=\widthSideBar, sidebar width right=0cm}

\makeatletter
    \newlength{\widthBeamerLeftMargin}
    \setlength{\widthBeamerLeftMargin}{\Gm@lmargin}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}
\newlength{\heightFigure}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
% Distance to the right margin
\newcommand{\measureRemainderToRightMargin}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
        % Measure distance to right text border
        \path let \p0 = (0,0), \p1 = (current page.east) in
        [/utils/exec={\pgfmathsetlength#1{\x1-\x0}\global#1=#1}];
    \end{tikzpicture}%
                                            }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuernadipiscing elit. Etiam lobor-tis facilisis sem. Nullam necmi et neque pharetra sollic-itudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ul-lamcorper, felis non sodalescommodo, lectus velit ultri-ces augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede.

    \hspace*{-0.9\widthBeamerLeftMargin}
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage={0.25\paperwidth}, valign=t}
        \hspace*{\fill} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuernadipiscing elit. Etiam lobor-tis facilisis sem. . \hspace*{\fill}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \hfill
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage={0.65\paperwidth}, valign=t}
        \includegraphics[height=5.2cm]{example-image-a}
    \end{adjustbox}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposal. It comes with two commands.

1. `\GetRemainingDistances` computes the remaining width and height.
2. `\GetScaleFactorFor` computes the scale factor such that the picture fits on the rest of the page. It measures the remaining horizontal and vertical space on the page and adds the picture in such a way that it fits. This is achieved by comparing the aspect ratio of the picture to the quotient of remaining vertical and horizontal space.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names},c]{beamer}

    \setbeamercovered{transparent=30}

    \usecolortheme{seahorse}
    \useoutertheme{miniframes}
    \useinnertheme{inmargin}

    \usepackage{adjustbox}

\newlength{\widthSideBar}
\setlength{\widthSideBar}{0.3\paperwidth}

\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=\widthSideBar, sidebar width right=0cm}

\makeatletter
    \newlength{\widthBeamerLeftMargin}
    \setlength{\widthBeamerLeftMargin}{\Gm@lmargin}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}
\newlength{\heightFigure}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
% Distance to the right margin
\newcommand{\GetScaleFactorFor}[2]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
        % Measure distance to right text border
        \path let \p1 = ($(current page text area.south east)-(0,0)$) in
        \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\aspectratio}{%
        height("\includegraphics{#1}")/width("\includegraphics{#1}")}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\restratio}{-\y1/\x1}
        %\typeout{\aspectratio,\restratio}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\scalefactor}{abs(ifthenelse(\aspectratio>\restratio,%
            -1*\y1/height("\includegraphics{#1}"),
            \x1/width("\includegraphics{#1}")))}
        \xdef#2{\scalefactor}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}                                      
\newcommand{\GetRemainingDistances}[2]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
        % Measure distance to right text border
        \path let \p1 = ($(current page text area.south east)-(0,0)$) in
        \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\restwidth}{\x1}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\restheight}{-\y1}%
        \xdef#1{\restwidth pt}\xdef#2{\restheight pt}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Example 1: move pic to the bottom right corner}

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, marmotae elit. Etiam lobor-tis
facilisis sem. Nullam necmi et neque pharetra sollic-itudin. Praesent imperdiet
mi nec ante. Donec ul-lamcorper, felis non sodalescommodo, lectus velit
ultri-ces augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede.

    \hspace*{-0.9\widthBeamerLeftMargin}
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage={0.25\paperwidth}, valign=t}
        \hspace*{\fill} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuernadipiscing
elit. Etiam lobor-tis facilisis sem. . \hspace*{\fill}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \GetScaleFactorFor{example-image-a}{\myscale}%
    \hfill\begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
        \includegraphics[scale=\myscale]{example-image-a}
    \end{adjustbox}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{Example 2: move pic to the bottom}

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, marmotae elit. Etiam lobor-tis
facilisis sem. Nullam necmi et neque pharetra sollic-itudin. Praesent imperdiet
mi nec ante. Donec ul-lamcorper, felis non sodalescommodo, lectus velit
ultri-ces augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede.

    \hspace*{-0.9\widthBeamerLeftMargin}
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage={0.25\paperwidth}, valign=t}
        \hspace*{\fill} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuernadipiscing
elit. Etiam lobor-tis facilisis sem. . \hspace*{\fill}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \GetScaleFactorFor{example-image-a}{\myscale}%
    \hfill\begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
        \includegraphics[scale=\myscale]{example-image-a}
    \end{adjustbox}\hfill{}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{Example 3: compute remaining distances and use them}

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, marmotae elit. Etiam lobor-tis
facilisis sem. Nullam necmi et neque pharetra sollic-itudin. Praesent imperdiet
mi nec ante. Donec ul-lamcorper, felis non sodalescommodo, lectus velit
ultri-ces augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede.

    \hspace*{-0.9\widthBeamerLeftMargin}
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage={0.25\paperwidth}, valign=t}
        \hspace*{\fill} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuernadipiscing
elit. Etiam lobor-tis facilisis sem. . \hspace*{\fill}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \GetRemainingDistances{\mywidth}{\myheight}
    \typeout{w=\mywidth,h=\myheight}
    \hfill \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
        \includegraphics[height=\myheight]{example-image-a}
    \end{adjustbox}


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, however, that one should use `\begin{frame}[t]` since otherwise this will never absolutely terminate since beamer always rearranges the slide. If you do not want to use `[t]`, use the following `overlay` code.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names},c]{beamer}

    \setbeamercovered{transparent=30}

    \usecolortheme{seahorse}
    \useoutertheme{miniframes}
    \useinnertheme{inmargin}

    \usepackage{adjustbox}

\newlength{\widthSideBar}
\setlength{\widthSideBar}{0.3\paperwidth}

\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=\widthSideBar, sidebar width right=0cm}

\makeatletter
    \newlength{\widthBeamerLeftMargin}
    \setlength{\widthBeamerLeftMargin}{\Gm@lmargin}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}
\newlength{\heightFigure}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
% Distance to the right margin
\newcommand{\FitPicToRestOfPage}[2][]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
        % Measure distance to right text border
        \path let \p1 = ($(current page text area.south east)-(0,0)$) in
        \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\aspectratio}{%
        height("\includegraphics{#2}")/width("\includegraphics{#2}")}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\restratio}{-\y1/\x1}
        %\typeout{\aspectratio,\restratio}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\scalefactor}{ifthenelse(\aspectratio>\restratio,%
            -1*\y1/height("\includegraphics{#2}"),
            \x1/width("\includegraphics{#2}"))}
        \xdef\scalefactor{\scalefactor}
        }
        node[anchor=north west,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt#1] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=\scalefactor]{#2}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}                                      

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuernadipiscing elit. Etiam lobor-tis
facilisis sem. Nullam necmi et neque pharetra sollic-itudin. Praesent imperdiet
mi nec ante. Donec ul-lamcorper, felis non sodalescommodo, lectus velit
ultri-ces augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede.

    \hspace*{-0.9\widthBeamerLeftMargin}
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage={0.25\paperwidth}, valign=t}
        \hspace*{\fill} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuernadipiscing
elit. Etiam lobor-tis facilisis sem. . \hspace*{\fill}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \FitPicToRestOfPage{example-image-a}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]